# PHP multiple url's check and do action

Tags: php

Can't figure out how to check multiple URL's and stop loading selected plugin. With other plugins it's all good when need to check only one page, but when it comes to multiple pages - ain't working at all.

Code:

```
  <?php

$request_uri = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH );

$is_admin = strpos( $request_uri, '/wp-admin/' );

if( false === $is_admin ){
    add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', function( $plugins ){

        global $request_uri;

        $berocket_filter_plugin = "woocommerce-ajax-filters/woocommerce-filters.php";

        $c = array_search( $berocket_filter_plugin, $plugins );

        if( false !== $c && in_array( strpos ($request_uri, ['/shop/','/product-category/'], true ) )){
            unset( $plugins[$c] );
        } 

        return $plugins;

    } );
}
```

I'm trying to check is page url is exactly 'shop' page slug, or contains '/product-category/' slug, as soon as I'm trying to use this array, it's not doing his work at all.
Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not a wordpress expert (I hate the bloody thing) but...

The strpos function second argument needs to be a string, you're passing in an array that evaluates to 0 I believe. And the 3rd argument is an offset on the sting, since you set it to true i believe that would evaluate to 1. So... what happens is:

```
in_array(strpos('myurl',0,1))
strpos('myurl',0,1) = 0 // as we're looking for a '0' in 'yurl'
```

consider working with the url as a dictionary. Instead of keeping it as a string run a no_empty explode to get something like:

```
['shop' => true,
'product-category' => true]
```

That way instead of running an array_search or strpos for each check you can simply invoke something along the lines of:

```
if(!isset($request_uri['wp-admin']) {...
    if (
       isset($request_uri['product-category']) || 
       (count($request_uri) === 1 && isset($request_uri['shop']))
    ) {...}
}
```

There is a neater way to write this but this should be simple to read and understand the logic.

Similar approach goes for the plugins array. The only difference between [$id => $value] and [$value => $id] is the fact that you need to run a search on the array and check if it's set instead of simply checking if it's set.